# How does the escape sequence '\b' work in C++? Alternate display method?

Tags: c++

So I've outputted a string of various ASCII characters. This program involves parts of this string being modified, and then re-displayed.

Instead of clearing the entire screen and re-displaying everything, which produces an unwanted flicker effect, I've decided on moving the cursor and then rewriting only the characters that have changed.

I'm moving the cursor with SetConsoleCursorPosition, part of windows.h.

However, once I try and cout something, it pushes all of the text in front of it ahead by a space; another unwanted effect.

In an attempt to fix this, I tried various forms of 'cout<<"\b";' to remove the old, unmodified character. But there was either no effect, or it actually added a space, which is obviously not a desired effect here.

I read somewhere that in order to remove the unwanted character that you actually have to use the escape sequence twice, Example: '\b\b', because the first one moves the cursor back a space, and the second one overwrites the character in front of it with a space (' ') or something like that.

'\b\b' didn't work either, unsurprisingly. Or maybe that is surprising, I don't actually know.

My question is: How do I remove the unwanted character? Or better yet, How do I overwrite text that has already been outputted with new text?

EDIT: I apologize, I'm running Windows 7

Comment: This has nothing to do with regex, so I removed the tag.

Comment: Have you tried using `\b` *without* using `SetConsoleCursorPosition`?

Comment: A common display trick is to have two consoles: one displayed one not. You draw what you want displayed on the second one, then you swap which one gets displayed. I don't know if Windows consoles offer features to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe clearing the `ENABLE_INSERT_MODE` with the [`SetConsoleMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686033(v=vs.85).aspx) function might help. It should prevent the console from inserting characters and pushing the old characters forward.